# React Native Redux useSelector is Undefined after Navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I am unable to get updated state after navigate to another state. I want to use my dataState which is initialized in reducer and updated via action. I used this state after dispatch on the Screen 1 but when i navigate to another screen its returning undefined.

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers.js';


export default createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

action.js

```
export const DATA_AVAILABLE = 'DATA_AVAILABLE';

export const addData = (data) => ({
    type: DATA_AVAILABLE,
    data
});
```

reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { DATA_AVAILABLE } from "./actions" 

let dataState = { data: [] };

const dataReducer = (state = dataState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DATA_AVAILABLE:
            return {...state, data: action.data};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    dataReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

HomeScreen.js Usage

```
const dataReducer = useSelector(state => state.dataReducer);
const { data } = dataReducer;

useEffect(() => getData(), []);

const getData = () => {
    setIsFetching(true);
    let url =
      "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/mesandigital/demo/instructions";
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(data => dispatch(addData(data)))
      .catch(error => alert(error.message))
      .finally(() => setIsFetching(false));
  };
```

Fetched data can be accessed with data constant. So it mean the state of dataState is updated after fetch. But when i navigate to other screen and tried to access the dataState, it returns undefined.
I am accessing the store state like this on there screen:

```
const dataReducer = useSelector(state => state.dataReducer);
const { data } = dataReducer;
```

data constant returns undefined. Am i missing something?

Comment: log state of the reducer using console.log(useSelector(state => state)); what is the result?

Comment: Its showing data like {"dataReducer":{"data":{"status":"1","data":"..." }}}

Comment: log dataReducer and see

Comment: if i do console.log(useSelector(state => state.dataReducer)); it gives error not defined

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the issue in my code. I was setting constant value right after useSelector.
I directly call the useSelector constant and it worked.Issue is that the other constant was not set when i call it. Thanks anyway